# enum size and initialization of variable

Tags: c++, enums, unsigned-char, uint8t

Even setting the size of an enum is not enough to be able to assign it to a variable of the same size (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edd287393f172abd):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

enum class Command : uint8_t
{
    CMD1    = 0x48,
    CMD2    = 0x97,
    CMD3    = 0x98,
    CMD4    = 0x92
};

int main()
{
    uint8_t test = Command::MACHINE_INFO;    
}
```

Is there a way I could use the enum to initialize my uint8_t variable without casting it?

Comment: You can define a unary `+` operator as a `friend` of your `enum class` then use `uint8_t test = +Command::MACHINE_INFO;`. I'm sure I got that trick from Stack Overflow but I can't find the post ...